# how do I find the index inside a recursion

Tags: c, recursion, indexing

(in c programming)
I have another index question if you don't mind.

I use this function to find the highest number in an array of integers:

```
int Find_max(int *array,int n){
    if(n==1) return array[0];
    int num1=Find_max(array,n/2);
    int num2=Find_max(array+n/2,n-n/2);
    if(num1>num2) return num1;
    return num2;
}
```

how do I get the index of the number I found? I'm not allowed to use any kind of loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost the same code (style retained):

```
int Find_max_index(int *array,int n){
    if(n==1) return 0;
    int index1=Find_max_index(array,n/2);
    int index2=n/2+Find_max_index(array+n/2,n-n/2);
    if(array[index1]>array[index2]) return index1;
    return index2;
}
```